# Rows for Columns Without Using Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, para

I will present my doubt in the form of an example:
I have a 30x10 dataframe, and I would like each row of each column to become a new column, so that at the end of the process i would have a 1x300 dataframe.
I currently do it through for, but I would like a code that would provide me with greater efficiency and speed.

Below I leave the current shape i use:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 30, ncol = 10))
data[,] <- sample(1:20,300,replace = TRUE)
newdata <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = 300))
j <- 1
for (i in 1:ncol(data)) {
  newdata[1,j:(j+29)] <- data[1:nrow(data),i]
  j <- j + 30
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
data.frame(t(c(data.matrix(data))))
```

Or if you want to use the matrix directly:

```
data.frame(t(c(matrix(nrow = 30, ncol = 10))))
```

**Output:**

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30 X31
1  1  9  4 13 10  9  5  8  2   2  11  18   4  11  16  17   9   3  10  18   4  18  15  12  20  17  19  18  14  11  18
  X32 X33 X34 X35 X36 X37 X38 X39 X40 X41 X42 X43 X44 X45 X46 X47 X48 X49 X50 X51 X52 X53 X54 X55 X56 X57 X58 X59 X60
1  14   7   6  11   4  14   2  10  19  15  18   6  13   6   7   2  15   1  20   7  18   1   4  11  16  17   8   4   8
  X61 X62 X63 X64 X65 X66 X67 X68 X69 X70 X71 X72 X73 X74 X75 X76 X77 X78 X79 X80 X81 X82 X83 X84 X85 X86 X87 X88 X89
1   2  16   4   8   4  16   9   8  15  12   1  14   8  13  12   3   2   7   1  19  13   4   9   5   6  18  14   2   3
  X90 X91 X92 X93 X94 X95 X96 X97 X98 X99 X100 X101 X102 X103 X104 X105 X106 X107 X108 X109 X110 X111 X112 X113 X114
1   9  13   7  12  20  16   7   9  18  16   18   12   16    1   18    1   19   18   16   17    7   17   20   13   16
  X115 X116 X117 X118 X119 X120 X121 X122 X123 X124 X125 X126 X127 X128 X129 X130 X131 X132 X133 X134 X135 X136 X137
1    2   11   16   17    1   14   13   18   12   19    2   10   14   17    7   15   18    2   11   10   19   14   13
  X138 X139 X140 X141 X142 X143 X144 X145 X146 X147 X148 X149 X150 X151 X152 X153 X154 X155 X156 X157 X158 X159 X160
1    9    4    1   20   11   16   18    8    6    2    5    9    9   20    9   12    1   15   16   11   17    1    9
  X161 X162 X163 X164 X165 X166 X167 X168 X169 X170 X171 X172 X173 X174 X175 X176 X177 X178 X179 X180 X181 X182 X183
1    8   10    5    5   15    5   19   11   20   13   11    2    8   12    8   18   14   10    8   11    2    2   17
  X184 X185 X186 X187 X188 X189 X190 X191 X192 X193 X194 X195 X196 X197 X198 X199 X200 X201 X202 X203 X204 X205 X206
1   16   16   10   16   11    9   18    9   18   11   20   14   11   18   18   16   12   11    5    8   13   17    9
  X207 X208 X209 X210 X211 X212 X213 X214 X215 X216 X217 X218 X219 X220 X221 X222 X223 X224 X225 X226 X227 X228 X229
1    9   17    5   19   14    7   18   13   19   10   18   14   14   10   10   19    1    7   17    1   10   15    4
  X230 X231 X232 X233 X234 X235 X236 X237 X238 X239 X240 X241 X242 X243 X244 X245 X246 X247 X248 X249 X250 X251 X252
1    9    9    6   18   15    4   11   12    6   17   20   19    7   17    4   10    5    2   13    7   18    2   15
  X253 X254 X255 X256 X257 X258 X259 X260 X261 X262 X263 X264 X265 X266 X267 X268 X269 X270 X271 X272 X273 X274 X275
1    8   20   18    8   20    2    5    5    8    7   17   17    5    4   20   15   16    7   12    4   15   17   20
  X276 X277 X278 X279 X280 X281 X282 X283 X284 X285 X286 X287 X288 X289 X290 X291 X292 X293 X294 X295 X296 X297 X298
1   20   20    9    6   12    2   14    1    8    3   11   20   18    7    6    8    9   12   15   14   11   20    6
  X299 X300
1   13   17
```

**Doublecheck:**

```
if(newdata == data.frame(t(c(data.matrix(data))))){
  print(TRUE)
} else {
  print(FALSE)
}

[1] TRUE
```